# Different voltages between same point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

In this circuit, we determine that the emf needs to be reversed and that its value is 108.75 V.

My confusion is that I thought the voltage between any two points must be the same irrespective of the path taken.

For instance, in the parallel group of 15.0 and 20.0 resistors, let's call the point on the right a and left b. From the top branch, V_ab = 108.75 - 15(4.25) = +45V. From the bottom branch, V_ab = (-2.25)20 = -45V.

I see how this is true from Kirchoff's loop rule, but it violates my previous intuition.

(A copy of the problem can be found in (PPT file): physics.wku.edu/~womble/phys260/ch26exp1.ppt)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I had previously misread which node was *a* and which was *b* in the question.

> V_ab = 108.75 - 15(4.25) = +45V

If *a* is on the right, and E = -108.75, then you should have

$$ V_{ab} = -108.75 + (15\Omega)(4.25\mathrm{V}) = -45\mathrm{V}$$

Comment: The current in this lower branch is flowing from b to a.  See (warning: powerpoint file) physics.wku.edu/~womble/phys260/ch26exp1.ppt for confirmation.

Comment: @sailor, not if E = -108.75 V.

Comment: I am confused because the solution to the problem shows that the current is indeed -2.25 A in the lower branch, so I don't follow what you are trying to say

Comment: On slide 10 it shows I_1 = -2.25 A. But notice that I_1 is from *b* to *a*. You want the current from *a* to *b*, so that is +2.25 A.

Comment: Ooops, I had *a* on the left and *b* on the right (see how much easier things would be if you just put the node labels on your schematic?). Will edit.

Comment: On the diagram I_1 is from a to b (Slide 10). And I_1 = -2.25 A. So current is flowing from b to a. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am also convinced of this because if we did not see 2.25 A from b to a in the bottom branch, it would not make sense to have 4.25 A in the top branch, since the circuit must have 2 A clockwise (4.25 - 2.25 = 2).